# Teradata count how many times a value appears in a column

Tags: split, case, teradata

I have a table that has a column called [Conditions met] but within each row it has several values surrounded by commas [0350,380,0999,300,0126,0356,0357,0333,0316] and I want to count how many clients I have for each condition. For example

0350 - 10 clients.

0126 - 20 clients.

0333 - 08 clients.

I have tried to use CASE WHEN but it does not bring me the complete data, if a client fulfilled two conditions it only adds or counts the first WHEN, the second occurrence is not taken.

Could you help me or guide me how to count correctly in these cases?

This is my database table and the CLIENT field is actually the [ Cliente ID ].

[image]

This is my code:

```
    CREATE MULTISET TABLE CONDICIONES_II AS (
    SELECT
        SUBSTR (FECHA_TRX, 1, 6) AS PERIODO,
        SUBSTR (FECHA_TRX, 7, 2) AS DIA,
        CASE
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0300%') THEN '0300'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0301%') THEN '0301'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0302%') THEN '0302'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0303%') THEN '0303'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0304%') THEN '0304'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0305%') THEN '0305'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0306%') THEN '0306'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0307%') THEN '0307'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0308%') THEN '0308'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0309%') THEN '0309'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0310%') THEN '0310'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0311%') THEN '0311'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0312%') THEN '0312'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0313%') THEN '0313'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0314%') THEN '0314'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0315%') THEN '0315'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0316%') THEN '0316'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0317%') THEN '0317'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0318%') THEN '0318'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0319%') THEN '0319'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0320%') THEN '0320'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0321%') THEN '0321'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0322%') THEN '0322'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0323%') THEN '0323'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0324%') THEN '0324'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0325%') THEN '0325'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0326%') THEN '0326'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0327%') THEN '0327'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0328%') THEN '0328'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0366%') THEN '0366'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0367%') THEN '0367'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0368%') THEN '0368'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0369%') THEN '0369'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0370%') THEN '0370'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0371%') THEN '0371'
            WHEN CONDICIONES LIKE ('%0372%') THEN '0372'
            END AS CONDICIONES,
        SUBSTR (hora_trx, 1, 2) AS HORA,
        COUNT (*) AS TRXS, -- This line is to count the times that the condition appears.
        COUNT (
            DISTINCT SUBSTR (hora_trx, 1, 2)||cod_cliente -- This line is to count the times that the condition appears but only once every hour
        ) AS UM
    FROM
        _VIEWS.V_BIGD_DDTT
    WHERE
        FECHA_TRX >= '20220801'
        AND FECREC= '20220801'
    GROUP BY
        PERIODO,
        DIA,
        CONDICIONES,
        HORA
) WITH DATA;
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: @Dale K,   Thanks for the observation, but the page required me to put that flag, I just corrected it so as not to confuse other people.

Comment: @ jarlh, The CASE STATEMENT is prioritizing the first occurrence. For example, if the conditions are repeated in any row, the CASE STATAMENT is only counting the first condition and the second does not add anything to it.

Comment: What would work better is using [`STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE`](https://www.docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-VantageTM-SQL-Functions-Expressions-and-Predicates/March-2019/String-Operators-and-Functions/STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE). This will split every comma delimited value in that column into its own row. Then you can count like normal.

Comment: @JNevill    Thanks, The database I work with has more than 5 million records, if I do the SPLIT, would it be too heavy?